# What does `not in small way` mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you tell me what does `not in small way` mean in following context :

> To work at this company you really have to have just desire to do something, and **not in small way**.

Comment: It means "this company" doesn't have an Anglophone working in the "slogans" department. Anyone could accidentally omit the article in *not in **a** small way*, but only a non-native speaker would be likely to come out with *you really have to have just desire...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should most likely have an article preceding small, i.e. *not in a small way*. It essentially means that the desire should be non-trivial, a desire to do something great.

Answer (score 2):

*In a big way*; to a large degree.

Literally, it doesn't necessarily mean in a big way, as something can be neither small, nor large, but somewhere in between. It's an example of negation as understatement which can ironically mean something is actually emphasised (referred to as *meiosis* or *litotes* in the study of rhetoric).

The writer or speaker's intention is that by using an expression that literally understates the "in a big way" of their message, they actually put more emphasis on it than if they just said "in a big way". I'm not convinced that they actually succeeded in this particular case. (Hey, meiosis can be difficult to pull off).

Answer (score 1):

It means *in a big way*.  Depending on context, it can mean *enthusiastically, vigorously, thoroughly, extensively* or other terms indicating a large amount of effort, involvement or commitment.